# Report Viewer is working in visual studio 2015 at local server but not working when application has been deployed to client side iis7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, report, reportviewer

We are facing this problem:

> An error occurred during local report processing.  The definition of
>   the report 'CBARReport.rdlc' is invalid.  An unexpected error occurred
>   in Report Processing.  Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I installed `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` but it is still returning the same error. My code is in vb.net and while I installed the assembly it is adding `loader.cs` in App_code which is also giving error.

Comment: Check if you have the dll for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0 in the bin of your website on the server.

Comment: yes. i am having dll in bin folder but still it is not working.

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll             Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.refresh, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll,   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL

Comment: And the version is 12.00?

Comment: no my version is 11.00

Comment: There's the problem download the 12.0 dll and put it in the bin folder and it should work.

Comment: oky i will try..also in this assembly have loader.cs page but my code is in vb.